# can't cd into directory with spaces

Tags: bashrc

I have tried all the ways of getting into a directory with spaces, and they all do not work.

```
mkdir "test folder"
```

#### Attempt #1

```
cd "test folder"

**bash: cd: test: No such file or directory**
```

#### Attempt #2

```
cd 'test folder'

**bash: cd: test: No such file or directory**
```

#### Attempt #3

```
cd test\ folder/

**bash: cd: test: No such file or directory**
```

#### Attempt #4

```
TEST=test\ folder

echo $TEST
**test folder**

cd $TEST

**bash: cd: test: No such file or directory**
```

this is my bash version: **GNU bash, version 4.2.24(1)-release (i686-pc-linux-gnu)**. Could it possibly be something is wrong with my `.bashrc`?

Comment: Is it possible you have an alias or procedure defined for `cd`?

Comment: YES!!! I had a script that changes the name of the window to the name of the file I was editting!! THANK YOU!!! Overlooked this :( hahaha

Comment: Glad I was able to help.  Have a great new year.

Answer (score 3):

There could be other hidden characters (other than a space....like maybe a TAB) in the directory name.....

Try:

```
 cd *folder
```

OR

```
 cd test*
```

and see if this works.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following `ls` switches to detective these types of problems:

```
   -b, --escape
          print C-style escapes for nongraphic characters

   -q, --hide-control-chars
          print ? instead of non graphic characters

   --show-control-chars
          show non graphic characters as-is (default unless program is `ls' and output is a terminal)

   -Q, --quote-name
          enclose entry names in double quotes
```

**NOTE:** The `--show-control-chars` is usually on by default.

#### Examples:

```
% touch normal_file
% touch "spacy_file "
% touch "ctrl_file^[^\^]"
```

**NOTE:** The 3rd file was created by pressing ...

- hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and press <kbd>V</kbd> & <kbd>3</kbd>
- hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and press <kbd>V</kbd> & <kbd>4</kbd>
- hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and press <kbd>V</kbd> & <kbd>5</kbd>

#### `-lb`

```
% ls -lb
total 0
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saml saml 0 Jan 13 21:22 ctrl_file\033\034\035
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saml saml 0 Jan 13 21:22 normal_file
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saml saml 0 Jan 13 21:22 spacy_file\
```

#### `-l`

```
% ls -l
total 0
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saml saml 0 Jan 13 21:22 ctrl_file???
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saml saml 0 Jan 13 21:22 normal_file
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saml saml 0 Jan 13 21:22 spacy_file
```

#### `-q`

```
% ls -q
ctrl_file???  normal_file  spacy_file
```

#### `-lq`

```
% ls -lq
total 0
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saml saml 0 Jan 13 21:22 ctrl_file???
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saml saml 0 Jan 13 21:22 normal_file
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saml saml 0 Jan 13 21:22 spacy_file
```

#### `-lQ`

```
% ls -lQ
total 0
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saml saml 0 Jan 13 21:22 "ctrl_file\033\034\035"
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saml saml 0 Jan 13 21:22 "normal_file"
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saml saml 0 Jan 13 21:22 "spacy_file "
```